# How to know a youtube movie is play or stop in UIWebview?

Tags: iphone, ios, uiwebview

I found a way to play youtube in webview

And this is my sample code :

```
NSString *youtubeHtmlStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<iframe class=\"youtube-player\" type=\"text/html\" width=\"328\" height=\"270\" src=\"http://www.youtube.com/embed/%@\" frameborder=\"0\"></iframe>",videoPath];
[webView loadHTMLString:youtubeHtmlStr baseURL:nil];
```

How to know the movie is playing now ???

When I click play icon , It log a message

> setting movie path:
>   http://o-o.preferred.fareastone-khh1.v3.lscache5.c.youtube.com/ ...

But I have no idea who log this message ???

Hope someone know the answer

Many thanks

Webber

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you will have to do with html is to use java-script. Didn't try it with Youtube personally, but Google documentation might be helpful: http://static.googleusercontent.com/external_content/untrusted_dlcp/www.google.com/en//events/io/2011/static/presofiles/youtube_iframe_player_the_future_of_embedding.pdf

In order to handle playback events inside your objective-c code, you could navigate the webpage to the url's like myplayer://stopped handle it with webview delegate method, of course not allowing it to change the page. that way the url will tell you what happened inside the html.

Answer (score 0):

It will not work on simulator try it on device and check the result.